# Receive notifications through PushBullet API

Tags: pushbullet

At the moment I'm playing a bit with the PushBullet API. I can send notifications, create new devices and so on but the only thing I can't is receive messages. I have created a web application and have created a new device over the pushbullet API but now if I send a notification to this device my web application is not informed about that. Of course I also need a handler method for this. Do you have any ideas how I can implement this in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen on the websocket for a tickle notification (this means there are new pushes available at https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes) https://docs.pushbullet.com/#stream

So whenever you get a tickle:

```
{"type": "tickle", "subtype": "push"}
```

you can do a request to:

```
https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes?limit=1
```

to get the most recent push.

Comment: Thank you for this works great! Is it right that I get **all** notifications from my account and have to decide (i.e. with the iden) if the notification was for my application?

Comment: Yes, there are very limited filtering options for /v2/pushes.  Just like limit and active.